# Will I lose all codes and files if I uninstall Pycharm and Python in macOS?

Tags: macos, tensorflow, pycharm, uninstallation

I am using the Pycharm platform for Python and Jupyter Notebook. So all my codes, files and packages are in Pycharm. Now I want to use TensorFlow and for that first, I have to uninstall Pycharm (I checked blogs and youtube, everybody is saying first uninstall everything like python, pycharm, etc). I am worried that all my files and codes would be lost.

Can someone guide me about this doubt? Will I lose everything if I uninstall Pycharm?

I am working on mac.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In PyCharm, right click on one of your scripts and select *Show in Explorer/File Manager*. This will show you where your files are stored. They are not stored *in PyCharm* but on your storage drive. PyCharm is just your editor with which you modify and run your scripts. If your scripts are located on a safe place on your disk, you are ok to remove pycharm (and python) without losing the files. Note that in case you have stored the files in your user/pycharm home (typically scratch files) they may be removed if you choose to *remove everything* during the uninstall process.

Comment: Right-click one of your scripts in PyCharm and choose *"Show/reveal in Finder"*. Navigate up one level in Finder until you come to a place that encompasses all your PyCharm scripts, then right-click that place and choose *"Compress XYZ"*. That will make a ZIP file of all your stuff - copy that to a safe place (maybe Dropbox or Google drive or a USB thumb drive) while you remove PyCharm.

Comment: No need to uninstall python and PyCharm, tensorflow could be installed in the python you're using and then successfully be used in PyCharm